# pytables, how to sort rows appended

Tags: python, sorting, pytables

In pytables (aka tables) you can append data according to the [tutorial](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/tutorials.html#appending-data-to-an-existing-table), and [docs](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html?highlight=table.itersorted#tables.Table.append).

How can I append unsorted data on the fly continuously received from a server to an existing sorted table?

In other words, I need to append rows not only to the end but also somewhere to the middle of a sorted table, because I need a table be always properly sorted.

Calling [Table.copy](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html?highlight=table.copy#tables.Table.copy) method with `sortby` parameter seems inefficient since my table is updated every second and contains millions of rows to "copysort" the whole table each time new data is received.

Comment: Insertion sort comes to mind... Rather than appending (append == "add at the end"), find the location the new row should be, and insert it in place. That's more efficient than a full resort on every new row (but less efficient than e.g. accumulating a few thousand new rows and batch-resorting, although that would violate ordering in between sort passes - depends on how strict your need is for maintaining order at "all times").

Comment: @twalberg Where can I find insert option in pytables docs? There is [Tables.append_where](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html?highlight=append_where#tables.Table.append_where) method but it seems to be about conditioning (append row if that row satisfies x condition, correct me if I'm mistaken), not about sorting or insertion.

Comment: Didn't mean to imply that I thought this was actually possible with pytables - I'm quite unfamiliar with the pytables API. That was intended more as a general comment. If you need to keep the thing sorted at all times, then perhaps a pytable isn't the right data structure to use... It's just that, algorithmically speaking (outside any particular language or framework), if you need to keep it sorted, then you need to insert new rows into the proper place, or append and re-sort, which is less efficient...